# Can't receive UDP packets over broadcast address, ArtNet

Tags: java, linux, sockets, udp, raspberry-pi

I am trying to receive UDP packets on the raspberry pi. I have created a simple java program to connect the network. (I have all relevant code below)

```
String myNetworkAddress = "10.0.0.11";
String myBroadcastAddress = "10.255.255.255";
// Setup network connection
    try {
        InetAddress nicAddress = InetAddress.getByName(myNetworkAddress);
        InetAddress baddr = InetAddress.getByName(myBroadcastAddress);
        dmx = new ArtNet(nicAddress, baddr);

        udpsocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        udpsocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        udpsocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(nicAddress, dmx.getPort()));
        udpsocket.setBroadcast(true);
        udpsocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        System.out.println("Opened socket " + udpsocket.getLocalAddress() + ":" + udpsocket.getLocalPort());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("can't open socket " + e);
    }

while (true) {
        if (udpsocket != null) {
            if (dmx.readPacket(udpsocket)) {
                i = dmx.getPacket();
// read packet and process 
 }
 }
 }
```

I am not able to receive anything from the broadcast, on a raspberry pi. But when I run this code on another computer, I am able to receive packets from the broadcast. This leaves me to believe that java is not given access to creating a socket, binding the port and that it is not the code but a security measure on the raspberry pi.

Things that I have tried:

- running program as sudo,
- updating permissions,
- changing user permissions, and
- changing IP tables to allow for the port 6454.

Ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:11:11:11
          inet addr:192.168.1.48  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:25333 (24.7 KiB)  TX bytes:77137 (75.3 KiB)
```

dhclient.conf (Used when no router/dhcp server is available, connection is made between a computer and raspberry pi with a static ip):

```
timeout 10;
lease {
    interface "eth0";
    fixed-address 10.0.0.10;
    option broadcast-address 10.255.255.255;
    option subnet-mask 255.0.0.0;
    option host-name "node.local";
    renew 2 2022/1/1 00:00:01;
    rebind 2 2022/1/1 00:00:01;
    expire 2 2022/1/1 00:00:01;
}
```

With no luck. any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of ifconfig? Can you capture the packets with tcpdump or wireshark or another packet sniffer? If so, can they be captured from the rasberry pi or only from the other system? What is the connection between the broadcasting application and the rasberry pi? Are they on the same host, connected through a router etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Binding on the NicAddress, it only accepts incoming packets from the network address. Binding to 0.0.0.0 Will allow incoming pacts from the broadcast IP as well as other IP addresses